# Balancing Circuit for 2S Battery Using MAX77958 and MAX77960

Tags: batteries, bms, usb-pd

I am currently working on designing a battery-powered device and have decided to use the [MAX77958](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX77958.pdf) and [MAX77960](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX77960-MAX77961.pdf) for the battery management system (BMS). While reviewing the datasheets and the [Evaluation Kit for the MAX77958/MAX77962](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX77958EVKIT-2S3.pdf), I noticed that the MAX77960 doesn't seem to have a dedicated balancing wire for 2S batteries.

My specific concern is related to the absence of a balancing feature for 2S batteries in the MAX77960, especially when compared to the direct connection of a 3S battery in the provided evaluation kit without a balancing mechanism.

I am wondering if a separate circuit is required to achieve the balancing function for a 2S battery configuration when using MAX77960? It seems like a crucial aspect for maintaining cell equality and extending the overall battery life. Additionally, I find it intriguing that professional designs showcased in the evaluation kit do not include a balancing mechanism for 2S batteries.

Am I missing something in the design considerations or is there a specific reason for not including a balancing feature for 2S batteries in the MAX77960? Any insights or advice from experienced designers would be greatly appreciated.